# angularjs ng-repeat key value pair with combined conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to do a "ng-repeat" with some particular condition on the key value pairs.
My json data is like:

```
mylist = {
  "Tom Hans": true,
  "Carl King": true,
  "anotherfield": "Josef Bush"
}
```

Or:

```
mylist = {
  "Tom Hans": true,
  "Carl King": true,
  "anotherfield": ""
}
```

two of my keys are some string format as above and their values are always "true", and there is another fixed key `"anotherfield"` which can have either an empty value or have some value like above.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in mylist" ng-if="val == true">
        {{key}}</li>
</ul>
```

here is the desired result:
the output for the first version of the variable:

```
Tom Hans
Carl King
Josef Bush
```

the output for the second version of the variable when the "anotherfield" is empty:

```
Tom Hans
Carl King
```

could somebody help me achieve this?

Comment: Why not just reformat your json data so the third field works the same way as the others?

Comment: Why such a strange data structure?

Comment: To use ng-switch-when see my answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in mylist" ng-if="val || val.length">
        {{ val.length ? val : key }}</li>
</ul>
```

`val || val.length` will match if `val` is true, or if its length is >0.

If the val has a length, it will display the val, otherwise the key.

Comment: This wont work as its the `val` he wants to show for the last field rather than the `key`

Comment: this is giving me `Tom Hans` `Carl King` `anotherfield` however i want the value of the `anotherfield` not its key, though.

Comment: @JeremyThille that's simple and good, I thinked about a ng-switch-when, that work also right?

Comment: Yeah def, there are several solutions. @FrankModica's and the other answers down here are just as good.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be simple yet explicit:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in mylist" ng-if="val">
        {{ val === true ? key : val }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would map this to array in controller which will cut down watchers and child scopes in view and simplify view .

```
$scope.objToArray = function(obj){      
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, key){
     if(obj[key] === true){
       a.push(key)
     }else if(typeof obj[key] === 'string' && obj[key].trim().length){
       a.push(obj[key])
     }
     return a;
  },[]);      
}
```

View

```
<li ng-repeat="item in objToArray(mylist)">
  {{item}}
</li>
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vYpejmocDTumVtcglxeb?p=preview)

---

Ideally however if you control data structure at source I would consider creating more friendly structure

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ask if value == true in an if statement, if the value is true, just use it, on the other hand, the value if is not "", may have a length, so, in hava script, if something is >0, is true, finally you can do an ng-switch-when:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in mylist" ng-switch="val">
    <li ng-switch-when="val"> {{key}}</li>
    <li ng-switch-when="val.length"> {{val}}</li>

</ul>
```